# How can I improve my quran recitation?

Tags: quran

as salaamu alaikum, any advice on reading the Quran faster? I can read but I read really slow and I sound dumb. the only time I have a good recitation is when i memorize the surah any advice? jazakallah khair for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn Arabic. Become fluent.

It may sound dismissive, but seriously that's all there is to it; if you don't know the language you're always going to be stuck working out every word letter by letter, syllable by syllable, and that's always going to slow you down.

It's equivalent to trying to read English (assuming that's your first language) phonetically, letter-by-letter, instead of just looking at a word and instantly recognizing it and how it's pronounced. Not to mention how your brain does a lot of heavy lifting predicting what the rest of the sentence is going to be based entirely on context of what you've read so far, which requires *understanding* what you've read so far, so you often already know what the next word is going to be before you've even looked at it. That's just how reading works.

Or, let me put it another way: If you're *not* already fluent in Arabic, stop worrying about reading slow and sounding dumb. Nobody is perfect when they're starting out, and if you're worried about stuff like that now you're never going to improve. Just stick with it and you'll get less dumb-soundy and more fast over time.

Comment: okay I understand thanks.